# Getting compiler errors for Toshiba Thrive kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I have the Toshiba Thrive 10.1", and recently got the kernel source for it. My end goal is to have desktop Linux run on it, such as Ubuntu.

I found a guide on how to get the B&N Nook Color on it, and I followed it, making modifications for Ubuntu (as I already had a Ubuntu ARM download), but ran into a snag: I'd get "/dev/tty0: No such file or directory". I'd try simlinking, but I'd end up with "No free VT available".

A little bit of Googling suggested that I needed to enable VT support. That was easy enough: Grab the NDK, the .config file, edit it with "CONFIG_VT=y". While I was in there, I modified it for CD support.

Then I exported for the Thrive's settings, and ran make. Asked me a couple questions, then it errored out on me:

```
  CC      arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.o

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:74: error: pllx causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:74: error: pllx causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:85: error: emc_0 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:85: error: emc_0 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:93: error: emc_1 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:93: error: emc_1 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:102: error: emc_2 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:102: error: emc_2 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:114: error: emc_3 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:114: error: emc_3 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:123: error: emc_4 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:123: error: emc_4 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:131: error: emc_5 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:131: error: emc_5 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:145: error: emc_6 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:145: error: emc_6 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:160: error: emc_dqsib_dly causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:160: error: emc_dqsib_dly causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:164: error: emc_quse_dly causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:164: error: emc_quse_dly causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:168: error: emc_clktrim causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:168: error: emc_clktrim causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:173: error: emc_autocal_fbio causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:173: error: emc_autocal_fbio causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:188: error: emc_autocal_interval causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:188: error: emc_autocal_interval causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:195: error: emc_cfgs causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:195: error: emc_cfgs causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:214: error: emc_adr_cfg1 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:214: error: emc_adr_cfg1 causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:228: error: emc_digital_dll causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:228: error: emc_digital_dll causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:239: error: emc_dqs_clktrim causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:239: error: emc_dqs_clktrim causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:245: error: emc_dq_clktrim causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:245: error: emc_dq_clktrim causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:251: error: emc_dll_xform_dqs causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:251: error: emc_dll_xform_dqs causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:258: error: emc_odt_rw causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:258: error: emc_odt_rw causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:269: error: arbitration_xbar causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:269: error: arbitration_xbar causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:273: error: emc_zcal causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:273: error: emc_zcal causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:278: error: emc_ctt_term causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:278: error: emc_ctt_term causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:287: error: xm2_cfgd causes a section type conflict

arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.c:287: error: xm2_cfgd causes a section type conflict

make[1]: *** [arch/arm/mach-tegra/pm-t2.o] Error 1

make: *** [arch/arm/mach-tegra] Error 2
```

My question right now is, what do I need to do to fix this? I have not made any modifications to the source code itself, just the config file.

Comment: A little bit of Googling suggest that I had the wrong GCC. Still didn't fix it. Another suggestion was to comment out some code. Not to be pushy, but I wouldn't mind a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Trurns out, I *did* have the wrong GCC. The guide I was using said to use 4.4.3, when I needed to use 4.6. Once I did that, I didn't have any compiler errors. A few warnings, but not much I can do about that.